# Please what am i doing wrong in this code

Tags: java

I wrote a sorting function it works sorts everything, but if there is a space between two words it sorts the space to the beginning and removes the last string element  why is this happening? i tried String.trim() method to get rid of white spaces but it didn't work, i need help

```
private void SortStringsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
         // TODO add your handling code here:
         String str = TextArea.getText();

     String[] words = str.split(" ");

        int length = words.length;
    String temp; 
    for(int i=0; i<=length-1; i++){
            for(int j=0; j <length-1;j++){
            if(words[i].compareToIgnoreCase(words[j]) == 0 ){}
            else if (words[i].compareToIgnoreCase(words[j]) < 0){   
                                temp = words[i].trim();
                words[i] = words[j].trim();
                words[j] = temp;
            }else{} 
        }
    }
        /*
    String str2="";
    for (int i=0; i < length-1; i++) {
            str2+=words[i]+" ";
        }
        */
        StringBuilder str2 = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i<length-1; i++) {
            str2.append(words[i]).append(" ");
        }
        TextArea.setText(str2.toString());

    }
```

Comment: Method identifiers in Java should start with lower-case. Why you're passing an `evt` argument you never use? Is `TextArea` a class or a class field?

Comment: You are splitting the input by space and how you are getting space between two words then?

Comment: @m0skit0 what method are you talking about?

Comment: what do you mean by this ` sorts the space to the beginning and removes the last string element`

Comment: @Renjith i have  to split with space because, if i don't then it will split them into characters not words

Comment: You only posted one method, so it must be that one.

Comment: @BhavikShah for instance i put "me ace   you" it gives " ace me" and when i add another space between ace and me " ace  me" then it becomes "  ace"

Comment: @Plaix...Ok.But if you split your input by space, then how are you getting space in words array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it will be best not to use `for(int i=0; i<=length-1; i++)` but rather `for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)`.

This is also the reason why your last element is removed - you've used `for(int i=0; i<length-1; i++)` instead of `for(int i=0; i<length; i++)`

EDIT:
And to disable the spaces you can use: `TextArea.setText(str2.toString().trim());`

Comment: i edited all but still after sorting the last element is gone and when i continuously click on the sort button it removes the last element till there is no word left.

Comment: The code that you **must** change is in your last loop. After you define a `StringBuilder` you iterate the array of words till the `length-2` (because your condition states `i<length-1`) member but what you really should do is to iterate the last member as well which is `length-1` - this is done by changing your condition to `i < length`.

Comment: Thanks i did it and it worked perfectly, now i have another problem, when i type all the words in one line it sorts perfectly. but when i press enter and type other words in another line, it doesn't sort all.

Comment: Can you please post your new code? And the text you are typing?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort "whatever" just use java.utils.Collections class.
It has sorting methods for elements that implement Comparable:

```
static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

Or you can specify your own comparator:

```
static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

It would be easier than writing and debugging your own sorting code.

Here is an example: http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/

Answer (score 0):

[There's no need to reinvent the wheel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)